# Undefined variable $attributes (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rainbow\resources\views\dashboard\options\edit.blade.php) --- relation between two models

Tags: laravel

There are two modals attributes  &  its options

the problem now in options edit blade

This part of code  was work correctly in create.blade

**but in edit.blade ** show this error.

Then I try to add this variable to the controller in several ways but still the same error appears

you can find my codes down, please help me

**edit.blade**

```
<div class="form-body">
    <h4 class="form-section">
        <i class="ft-home"></i> Option name
    </h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectinput1"> Choose a feature
                </label>
                <select name="attribute_id" class="select2 form-control" >
                    <optgroup label="Choose a feature ">
                        @if($attributes && $attributes -> count() > 0)
                            @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                                <option
                                    value="{{$attributes -> id }}">{{$attributes -> name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
                @error('attribute_id')
                <span class="text-danger"> {{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
```

**attribute model**

```
public function options() {
    return $this->hasMany(Option::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

**option model**

```
public function attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

**controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //get specific options and its translations

    $option = Option::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->find($id);
    if (!$option)
        return redirect()->route('admin.options')->with(['error' => 'this option is not available']);

    return view('dashboard.options.edit', compact('option'));
}

public function update($id, OptionsRequest $request)
{
    try {
        //validation

        //update DB

        $option = Option::find($id);
        if (!$option)
            return redirect()->route('admin.options')->with(['error' => 'this option is unavailable']);

        if (!$request->has('is_active'))
            $request->request->add(['is_active' => 0]);
        else
            $request->request->add(['is_active' => 1]);

        $option->update($request->except('_token', 'id'));

        //save translations
        $option->name = $request->name;
        $option->save();

        DB::commit();

        return redirect()->route('admin.options')->with(['success' => 'success']);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.options')->with(['error' => 'fail, try again later']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

**i cannot find any $attributes variable in your controller that you are sending to your blade!!**

so when you dont send data to your blade, it is impossible to use that data in blade

send it to blade

or you can put your $options in @foreach and then get every option's attribute like this:

```
@foreach($options as $option)
    $option->attributes
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

in edit method there no $attributes, you should write $option in place of $attributes edit.blade.php,
f